# How can I read a Grails 2.x project dependencies programmatically?

Tags: grails

I have a Grails 2.x project with a BuildConfig.groovy, and I need to read the dependencies programmatically, using some kind of API that will process the file so that I can read how it would be at runtime. So far I have been unable to locate the right class in the Grails API for processing a BuildConfig.groovy.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple command to generate your dependency report -

```
grails dependency-report runtime
```

reference - [doc](http://docs.grails.org/2.2.5/ref/Command%20Line/dependency-report.html)

Comment: I am not looking for a report. I need to read them programmatically.